Proper wall assembly for finishing basement with half-concrete foundation
I am thinking of finishing my Ontario basement and have a question about proper wall assembly.
The grade of the lawn slopes down from the front of the house to the back, so that a concrete foundation is used up to about a foot above the lawn, and then a wood frame construction is used above that.
As a result, in the front of the basement, the wall is completely concrete (with pink bat insulation taped on under a plastic sheet), where as in the back the concrete foundation is about 4 foot tall, with wood-frame above that (with bat insulation in the stud bays and a plastic sheet taped over everything).
 In the foreground, you can see a portion of the wall that's split concrete/wood frame and in the background, the wall is completely concrete. It "steps" down like this for the length of the wall.
At it's tallest, the wood frame portion of the wall looks like this: 
If the walls were fully concrete all the way around, I would glue rigid foam up against the concrete (with a 2 mm separation to the concrete), then have 2x4 wall assembly with bat insulation between studs, then finally 1/2 inch drywall.
However, I don't know if this assembly is appropriate in the upper part of the walls, where there's already wood-frame. Is it ok to extend my proposed assembly all the way to the ceiling, or could I just get away with having a drywall layer over the insulated wood-frame part. If so, how would I handle the transition from concrete to wood-frame?

If you don't want a shelf for knicknacks just build new framing from floor to ceiling.  You'll lose a bit of floor space, but you could lay the studs flat so the framing is only 1.5" thick.
Otherwise, you build a knee wall and connect its top to the existing framing, and you get your knicknack shelf.
You will, of course, need to build chases for the HVAC ducts, and a bumpout for the sanitary drain, either way.  Probably need to neaten up your (A/C?) piping as well.
Personally, I think the first method is the easy button.
